# i cant Implement Pictures to my Kivy pages = white screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Hey guys i am totally new to programming starting my first project and i wanted to implement pictures on my pages but instead i just get white screens

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Window.size = (1000,700)

Builder.load_string("""

<Login>
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Benutzername:"
                font_size: 30

            TextInput
                id: benName
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30

            Label:
                text: "Passwort:"
                font_size: 30

            TextInput:
                password: True
                multiline: False
                id: passwort
                font_size: 30

        Button:
            text: "Anmelden"
            id: btn
            size_hint: (1.,0.3)
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.loginPopup()

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10

            Button:
                text: "1"
                font_size: 30
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "fenster11"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Button:
                text: "2"
                font_size: 30
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "fenster12"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Button:
                text: "3"
                font_size: 30
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "fenster13"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Button:
                text: "4"
                font_size: 30
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "fenster14"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Button:
                text: "5"
                font_size: 30
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "fenster15"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

            Button:
                text: "6"
                font_size: 30
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "fenster16"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"



""")

class Login(Screen):
    ben = StringProperty()
    pw = StringProperty()
    knopf =ObjectProperty()
    def loginPopup(self):
        if self.ben == "" or self.pw == "":
            popup = Popup(title ='Fehler',
            content = Label(text="Es wurde kein Passwort oder Benutzername angegeben"),
            size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))
            popup.open()
        if self.ben == "Name" and self.pw == "Passwort":
                self.knopf.background_color = [0.,1.,0.,1.]
        else:
                self.knopf.background_color = [1.,0.,0.,1.]


class geheimerBereich(Screen):
    pass

class weitereInformationen(Screen):
    pass
class Fenster11(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster12(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster13(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster14(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster15(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster16(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster17(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster18(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster19(Screen):
    pass

class Fenster20(Screen):
    pass




Builder.load_string("""
<weitereInformationen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Weitere Informationen"
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "fenster11"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
""")


Builder.load_string("""
<fenster11>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Fenster 11"
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "fenster12"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
""")

Builder.load_string("""

<fenster12>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Fenster 12"
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "fenster13"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                
<fenster13>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Fenster 13"
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "fenster14"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"    
                
<fenster14>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Fenster 12"
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "fenster15"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"   
                
                
                
<fenster15>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Fenster 12"
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "fenster16"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"    
                
                
<fenster16>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        Image:
            id: img1
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left" 
""")

Builder.load_string('''
<CustomLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        id: page1
    BoxLayout:
        id: page2
    BoxLayout:
        id: page3
''')


class CustomLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        
        img1 = Image(source='venv/IMG/EXTIN.jpg')
        img2 = Image(source='path/to/image2.png')
        img3 = Image(source='path/to/image3.png')

        
        self.ids.page1.add_widget(img1)
        self.ids.page2.add_widget(img2)
        self.ids.page3.add_widget(img3)


ms = ScreenManager()
ms.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
ms.add_widget(geheimerBereich(name='geheim'))
ms.add_widget(weitereInformationen(name='weitere_infos'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster11(name='fenster11'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster12(name='fenster12'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster13(name='fenster13'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster14(name='fenster14'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster15(name='fenster15'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster16(name='fenster16'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster17(name='fenster17'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster18(name='fenster18'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster19(name='fenster19'))
ms.add_widget(Fenster20(name='fenster20'))







class StartApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ms

if __name__ == "__main__":
        StartApp().run()


<fenster16>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        Image:
            id: img1
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left" 



<fenster16>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Fenster 16"
            font_size: 30
        Image:
            source: 'your_image_path/image_name.png'
        Button:
            text: "weiter"
            font_size: 30
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "geheimerBereich"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

tried a few ways to implement it but the only result was a white screen.
the picture should be displayed here just above a button
showed both ways down below

Comment: Your CustomLayout is never being called as you are building the ScreenManager (ms) as your main layout not the CustomLayout.

Comment: so what have i to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you would like the images to appear.  If you want them to appear as a background behind the buttons, TextInputs and Labels. You can add the image directly in your  screen kv setup.
ie.

```
<Login>
    id: page1
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    Image:
        source: 'venv/IMG/EXTIN.jpg'
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
...
```

Make sure you are specifying the path to the image correctly.  They are relative to the application root (Where ever the .py files that start's your application is located). If the image is in the same directory as your main .py file then you don't specify a path.  If the image is in the IMG directory then you would specify it as: IMG/image.jpg

If you want to trigger the image change by a button or other Widget then you can do the following as an example.

First add an id to the Image:

```
<Login>
    id: page1
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    Image:
        id: login_image
        source: 'venv/IMG/EXTIN.jpg'
```

You can then change the source in a method in the Login Class

```
    def loginPopup(self):
        if self.ben == "" or self.pw == "":
            popup = Popup(title='Fehler',
                          content=Label(text="Es wurde kein Passwort oder Benutzername angegeben"),
                          size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
            popup.open()
        if self.ben == "Name" and self.pw == "Passwort":
            self.knopf.background_color = [0., 1., 0., 1.]
            self.ids.login_image.source = 'path/to/image1.png'
        else:
            self.knopf.background_color = [1., 0., 0., 1.]
            self.ids.login_image.source = 'path/to/image2.png'
```